# How can I simplify this equation? $x\sqrt[3]{x}+4x^{\frac{4}{3}}-5\sqrt[3]{x^4}$

Tags: quadratics

How can I simplify this equation step-by-step?

$x\sqrt[3]{x}+4x^{\frac{4}{3}}-5\sqrt[3]{x^4}$

---

My attempt:

$=x*x^{\frac{1}{3}}+4x^{\frac{4}{3}}-5x^{\frac{4}{3}}$

$=(x*x^{\frac{1}{3}})+(4x^{\frac{4}{3}}-5x^{\frac{4}{3}})$

$=x*x^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{4}{3}}$

Comment: @dxiv I edited my question.

Comment: it's zero ... ... note that $ x = x ^{ \frac 3 3}$

Comment: @CaioTarifa Then all you have to remember is that $x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv oh... x^(3/3) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X^{\frac{4}{3}} +4X^{\frac{4}{3}}-5X^{\frac{4}{3}} = 0$

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain me how?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^{1/3}= t$.

The given expresssion simplifies to:

$tx+4t^4-5t^4$
$\implies (t(x-t^3))$ $\implies x^{1/3}.(x-(x^{1/3})^3) = x^{1/3}(x-x) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$x\sqrt[3]x+4x^\frac{4}{3}-5\sqrt[3]x^4 = \sqrt[3]x^4+4\sqrt[3]x^4-5\sqrt[3]x^4 = \sqrt[3]x^4(1+4-5) = \sqrt[3]x^4(0) = 0$$